# SubString/subsequence in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody help me in formatting the below string to display the final result as "**Mark, Anthony**"  i have been using substring in javascript to format and do we have anything like subsequence to make these format in a single line code?

```
var res="undefinedMark, Anthony," 
var final = res.substring(9, res.length); // removes undefined
var finalOP = final.substring(0, final.length - 9); // removes the final ,
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `String.replace` method:

```
var final = res.replace(/undefined/,'') //=>replace undefined with ''
               .replace(/,$/,'');       //=>replace the last ','
```

Comment: Hi Thameem, glad I could help, happy coding!